# Enabling access to my account from work computer

Tags: support, login, merge-accounts, duplicate-accounts

I have two laptops: a personal one and a work one. From the personal one, I log in to my Stack Exchange account using my personal Google Account, which I don't want to use on my work laptop (e.g. because it is linked to my personal mailbox and my employer should not have access there). Still, I want to share the Stack Exchange account between the two machines.

On my previous job, I added another Google account (provided by the employer) in [Edit Profile & Settings > My Logins](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials) and removed it after my contract ended.

Now, with my new employer, I don't have any work Google account. I **tried to add my work e-mail address and password on the [Add more logins form](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent)**, a verification mail was sent there and I followed the link inside. I was surprised to find that a **new account was created** for me.

Maybe it was because I access the work mailbox from my work laptop and I am not logged in to my Stack Exchange account there. I decided to delete the new account and try again, this time opening the link sent to my work mailbox on my personal laptop. The form insisted that the work e-mail address is in use and I ended up with stopping the deletion somehow and sending a **[request for merge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) of the two accounts**.

My request arrived on Thursday early in the morning EDT. In the morning, I received a response with instructions. Friday early morning, I followed them, proved my ownership of both accounts and replied with the URLs of the profiles to be merged as instructed (even though I have already filled them in the contact us form). Since then, nothing happened the whole Friday.

**When can I expect the merge to be finished?** Was this whole procedure really necessary? **How should I proceed the next time I want to provide my work laptop on another job with access to my Stack Exchange account?**

Comment: Allow for [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) ...

Comment: They don't have a 24/7 helpdesk so the earliest something might happen is on Monday, if that is not some holiday in the US. I believe these kind of merges are a manual process anyway so you need a human to be available to process your request. Those humans are a scarce resource though.

Comment: *Was this whole procedure really necessary?* They don't want users hijacking other people's accounts by merging them with their own.

Comment: *How should I proceed the next time I want to provide my work laptop on another job with access to my Stack Exchange account?*

Create an email address specifically for logging into sites you want to use at home and at work. That way you don't even have to change the email address when you change jobs.

Comment: A separate Google account for use at work can work if I change its password and [remove the device from recently used](https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity) (see [Sign out of someone else’s device](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/54490?hl=en)) when changing jobs, @BSMP. That should destroy even a permanent login. I am not sure, though, if backup codes cannot be extracted by my employer while I am their employee and used later to gain access to my work account after I change jobs. Still, a burner identity seems safer to me.

Comment: *Was this whole procedure really necessary?* was meant to be about the procedure of setting up access to Stack Exchange account for an identity that I plan to throw away in the future and replace by another one. I get the reasons why accounts merge is a very sensitive operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday afternoon, after 10 days from the day I verified my ownership of the accounts, the two accounts were finally merged and Stack Overflow notified me by a reply to the e-mail thread started by my merge request.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically answering this (since I'm no employee and wouldn't really have a clue on where to begin guesstimating your first question):

> How should I proceed the next time I want to provide my work laptop on another job with access to my Stack Exchange account?

For the security you're looking for, the simplest way to accomplish this would be to **use a separate profile** dedicated *exclusively* to your personal Google account.  **Don't synchronize tabs between the two** since your employer will still have the privilege of seizing your laptop and/or searching it for anything they wish.

Comment: Do you mean I should keep personal and work accounts separate, both on Google and on [SO]? That's very inconvenient. I identified two personal resources I want to use at work and thus potentially compromise them. One is an SSH account where I am able to remove the key generated for my work laptop from authorized_keys and inspect that nothing malicious was done to the account. If I got locked out by an attacker, I am able to regain access by contacting the admin. The other resource is my Stack Exchange account where I'd like to get a similar trade-off between security and convenience.